# How to Model Complex Objects in Redis

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, caching, redis

I am looking to use Redis as Cache for complex data. Consider this example, I want to store and retrieve AssetType data. One AssetType can have multiple AspectTypes. So, AspectType itself is another entity. These would have a many to many relationship.

When I want to store the AssetType in Cache, I want the AspectType to be stored in new cache and somehow carry the reference. So, there are no duplicates of AspectTypes stored in every AssetType.
Basically, the structure should be:

```
Cache1: AssetType
key: at1, value: {at1, sameple description, [referenceTo-asp1, referenceTo-asp2]}
key: at2, value: {at2, sameple description, [referenceTo-asp2, referenceTo-asp3]}

Cache2: AspectType
key: asp1, value: {asp1, sample description}
key: asp2, value: {asp2, sample description}
key: asp3, value: {asp3, sample description}
```

This is very easy when I do it through Database using JPA. But, is there any efficient way to do this in Redis?

Comment: is it not possible to rather use an in memory database like H2? Then you can use your working JPA solution.

Comment: (It's not a direct answer because it's not in Java... and as the question is not java-related I believe you expect the answer to be)

If you know how to code in C or C++ then you can create a simple Redis module (it looks like an easy 30-60min task) that would have a global dictionary of all AspectType, and then in a single key it would store AssetTypes with pointers to AspectTypes.

You could also modify Redis sources to use global string dictionary (I think that they tried to do something like this but in the end decided not to), but again, that would require you to write in C...

Answer (score 0):

There are many efficient ways to do this in Redis. You have a few design decisions to make though.

First, you can have a key of hash type per AssetType, or one hash for all your AssetTypes.

**A key per AssetType**:

```
HSET AssetType:at1 name at1 desc "sample description" aspects "asp1,asp2,asp3"
HSET AssetType:at2 name at2 desc "sample description" aspects "asp1,asp2"
```

You can always use `SCAN 0 MATCH AssetType:*` to loop through your AssetTypes.

**One hash for all your AssetTypes**, serialize each AssetType, say with JSON:

```
HSET AssetTypes at1 "{'name':'at1','desc':'sample description','aspects':['asp1','asp2','asp3']}"
HSET AssetTypes at2 "{'name':'at2','desc':'sample description','aspects':['asp1','asp2']}"
```

The same decision applies to AspectTypes. The main trade-off here is if you may want to retrieve/update a given field of one item at a time, or you always retrieve/update the whole item.

Then, you use the referenced AspectType id to retrieve the details.

Another design decision is if you store the references with the main item, or you **store the references in a separate key**. For example, you could use a set to store the references to the aspects:

```
HSET AssetType:at1 name at1 desc "sample description"
SADD AspectsPerAsset:at1 asp1 asp2 asp3
```

Sets are helpful here as they only maintain unique members, simplifying your CRUD operations.

For example, this allows you to get the common aspects for two or more AssetTypes:

```
SINTER AspectsPerAsset:at1 AspectsPerAsset:at2 AspectsPerAsset:at3
```

Note so far we have done a one-to-many relationship. Here is an [article on many-to-many](http://panuoksala.blogspot.com/2015/09/redis-many-to-many.html). In this case, you would also maintain the references to AssetTypes per Aspect:

```
HSET AssetType:at2 name at2 desc "sample description"
SADD AspectsPerAsset:at2 asp1 asp2
SADD AssetsPerAspect:asp1 at2
SADD AssetsPerAspect:asp2 at2
```

This allows you to get all AssetTypes for a given AspectType, the AssetTypes that share a few aspects with `SINTER`, or say the AssetTypes that have one or more of a given set of AspectTypes:

```
SUNION AssetsPerAspect:asp1 AssetsPerAspect:asp2 at2
```

I tried to illustrate a few patterns for you. There may be others even better based on the specifics of your use case.